# Which transmission fluid does a 2014 Honda Fit GP5 Hybrid use?

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, fit

I have a 2014 Honda Fit GP5 Hybrid, and I would like to know what gear box oil I must use and at what mileage interval to change it?